# How to obtain the mirror image of an array (MATLAB)?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Given an array:

```
array1 = [1 2 3];
```

I have to reverse it like so:

```
array1MirrorImage = [3 2 1];
```

So far I obtained this ugly solution:

```
array1MirrorImage = padarray(array1, [0 length(array1)], 'symmetric', 'pre');
array1MirrorImage = array1MirrorImage(1:length(array1));
```

Is there a prettier solution to this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**UPDATE:** In newer versions of MATLAB (R2013b and after) it is preferred to use the function [`flip`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) instead of [`flipdim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipdim.html), which has the same calling syntax:

```
a = flip(a, 1);  % Reverses elements in each column
a = flip(a, 2);  % Reverses elements in each row
```

---

Tomas has the right answer. To add just a little, you can also use the more general [`flipdim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipdim.html):

```
a = flipdim(a, 1);  % Flips the rows of a
a = flipdim(a, 2);  % Flips the columns of a
```

An additional little trick... if for whatever reason you have to flip BOTH dimensions of a 2-D array, you can either call `flipdim` twice:

```
a = flipdim(flipdim(a, 1), 2);
```

or call [`rot90`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html):

```
a = rot90(a, 2);  % Rotates matrix by 180 degrees
```

Comment: Re: your edit, you can also just use `b = a(end:-1:1);` to flip ALL dimensions of a matrix.

Comment: One caveat to that option is that the matrix appears to get reshaped into a 1-by-length(a) vector, so you would have to call RESHAPE afterwards. This may be version specific (I am running MATLAB ver. 7.1).

Comment: I'm a bit late to this party, but I was just doing this problem (so thanks for the answers!), and to stop the requirement of using reshape (when flipping all dimensions), you can instead of using `b = a(end:-1:1);`, you can just use `b = a(end:-1:1,end:-1:1);`. Of course, if your matrix `a` has a lot of dimensions, you may not want to write all that out, so you could do `sz_a =size(a), b  =a(end:-1:1), a = reshape(a,sz_a)`.

Answer (score 20):

Another simple solution is

```
b = a(end:-1:1);
```

You can use this on a particular dimension, too.

```
b = a(:,end:-1:1); % Flip the columns of a
```

Comment: Good point. END makes things cleaner and easier to read by removing arguments like "length(a)".

Answer (score 14):

you can use

```
rowreverse = fliplr(row) %  for a row vector    (or each row of a 2D array)
colreverse = flipud(col) % for a column vector (or each column of a 2D array)

genreverse = x(end:-1:1) % for the general case of a 1D vector (either row or column)
```

http://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=149926&page=5

Answer (score -1):

Use that man:%to array's mirror r=input('insert rows');c=('insert columns')b=size(x); r=b(1);c=b(2); a=0; y(r,c)=0;
for i=1:r n=0; g=r-a; a=a+1; for j=1:c n=n+1;d(i,j)=x(g,n); end
end disp(y)